# How to fetch data using ajax and render element as a Bootstrap List Group Item in a List Group

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, bootstrapping

I am trying to get json data from external link using AJAX and it's not printing the output. I tried in the following way and it's not worked for me. And I'm not sure how to render element as a Bootstrap List Group Item in a List Group

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script     src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="fetchBtn">Fetch</button>
<ul id="results"></ul>
<script>
$(document).ready(fuction(){
$('fetchBtn').click(function(){
$.ajax({
 type: 'get',
 url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
 data: {},
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function (users){
 user.forEach(function(user){
$('#result').append('<li>' + user.name+ '</li>');
});
 };

error: function(xhr, status,errorThrown){
};
complete: function(xhr, status){
}
});
});
render() {
return (
<div>
<h1>{`users`}</h1>
<ul>
    {users.state.posts.map(post =>
        <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
          )}
    </ul>
  </div>

);
}
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of typos. I've tried to fix all of them. The remaining problem is with the `render()` function, which I don't really understand what it should do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script     src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="fetchBtn">Fetch</button>
<ul id="results"></ul>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('fetchBtn').click(function(){
$.ajax({
 type: 'get',
 url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
 data: {},
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function (users){
 users.forEach(function(user){
$('#result').append('<li>' + user.name+ '</li>');
});
 },

error: function(xhr, status,errorThrown){
},
complete: function(xhr, status){
},
});
});
render() {
return (
<div>
<h1>{`users`}</h1>
<ul>
    {users.state.posts.map(post =>
        <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
          )}
    </ul>
  </div>

);
}
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, i got a syntax error, missing ")" after argument list.